# We know that moving charge creates a magnetic field, so, does that created magnetic field have any effect on the motion of that very charged particle

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I understand that a moving charge creates a magnetic field, the question is, does that created magnetic field have any effect on the motion of that very charged particle in simple terms does that created magnetic field contribute to the force on that very moving charge?

NB: I am referring to a quantum particle

Comment: Hello, Cirus. I think your question will receive more responses, if you put the question directly in the title . Since, the actual question is short enough, it can fit in the title. Once people click on it, they can read the whole body to get the detailed explanation, but having the short question in the title  will be easier for people who just glance at the list of questions

Comment: Are you asking this about a quantum particle? Particle can mean many things.

Answer (score 0):

A charged body in motion does generate some magnetic field, but does so
in a direction perpendicular to its velocity (circumferential around
the axis of motion).   The effect of such a charge impinging on its own field generates a force perpendicular to BOTH the velocity of the
charge, and to the field, which is... inward.

The effect is called a Z-pinch, and is responsible for the narrow tracks left in
soil by lightning bolts... but is relatively unspectacular in less intense
currents.

This kind of pinch is a major concern in
fusion reactor research, since it would contain the charges in
fully ionized gasses.

Comment: I have the impression  z pinch  needs many charged particles in the same direction. I do not think that a single electron at constant velocity would be affected by "pinch"

Comment: I wasn't suggesting 'compressive force' on an elementary particle.   More familiar magnetic compression is seen in 'coin shrinker' items, like  here <http://www.capturedlightning.com/frames/shrinkergallery.html>

Answer (score 0):

A charge is always at rest with regard to itself, so it won't see its own magnetic field. A magnetic field is only seen by other particles in case they are not co-moving with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If the charge is considered point-like, then no, it does not feel its own field while in a uniform motion. But an accelerated or decelerated charge has a small "radiation friction:reaction" effect. Read R. Feynman lectures, chapter 28.